# Runnable on pusher and popper classes of bounded queue using java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class called Bounded Queue that pushes in and pops out variables from an ArrayList.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BoundedQueue {
    private  ArrayList<String> Queue = new ArrayList<>();
    private int size;

    public BoundedQueue(int maxsize) {
        this.size= maxsize;
    }

    synchronized void push(String s) {
        while (Queue.size() == this.size) {
            try {
                wait();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (this.Queue.size() < this.size) {
            notifyAll();
        }
        this.Queue.add(s);
        System.out.println("Pushed: "+ s + "/" + Queue.size());
    }

    synchronized String pop() {
        while (this.Queue.size() == 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (this.Queue.size() >= 1) {
            notifyAll();
        }
        int size = Queue.size() - 1;
        String curr = Queue.get(0);
        System.out.println("Popped: "+ curr + " / " + String.valueOf(size));
        return this.Queue.remove(0);
    }
}
```

I need help implementing a runnable class.

```
/*A class Pusher which implements Runnable. The constructor of this class should receive an instance of BoundedQueue, a name, and a number iterations. The run() method of this class should call push on the given instance of BoundedQueue the specified number of times, with a loop having an index variable whose value varies from 1 to the number iterations; the argument passed to push should be a String which consists of the value of the index variable plus the name.*/

class Pusher implements Runnable {
    Pusher(BoundedQueue q, String name, int iterations) {
    }

    public void run() {
    }
}

/*A class Popper which implements Runnable. The constructor of this class should receive an instance of BoundedQueue and a number iterations. The run() method of this class should call pop on the given instance of BoundedQueue the specified number of times.*/
class Popper implements Runnable {
    Popper(BoundedQueue q, int iterations) {
    }
    public void run() {
    }
}

/*A class Popper which implements Runnable. The constructor of this class should receive an instance of BoundedQueue and a number iterations. The run() method of this class should call pop on the given instance of BoundedQueue the specified number of times.*/
public class QueueUser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the question. "I need help" is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

The comments for classes `Pusher` and `Popper` essentially tell you how to implement them.

```java
class Pusher implements Runnable {
    private int  iterations;
    private BoundedQueue  queue;
    private String  name;

    Pusher(BoundedQueue q, String name, int iterations) {
        queue = q;
        this.name = name;
        this.iterations = iterations;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++) {
            queue.push(name + "_" + i);
        }
    }
}

class Popper implements Runnable {
    private int  iterations;
    private BoundedQueue  queue;

    Popper(BoundedQueue q, int iterations) {
        queue = q;
        this.iterations = iterations;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            String name = queue.pop();
            System.out.println("Retrieved: " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the `run` method takes no arguments, variables used in that method are usually class members. Hence when the comment tells you what perameters the class constructor requires, that means you probably need a separate class member for each constructor argument.

The comments also tell you what the `run` method in each class should do.

Now for the driver class, i.e. `QueueUser`. You need to launch a `Pusher` and a `Popper` in separate threads. Since JDK 5, the recommended way to launch several threads is via an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class QueueUser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BoundedQueue bq = new BoundedQueue(1000);
        Pusher pusher = new Pusher(bq, "Pusher", 100);
        Popper popper = new Popper(bq, 100);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        es.execute(pusher);
        es.execute(popper);
        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

When I ran the above code, this is the output I got.
(I suggest you experiment with different `int` arguments when calling the constructors for classes `BoundedQueue`, `Pusher` and `Popper`.)

```
Pushed: Pusher_1/1
Pushed: Pusher_2/2
Pushed: Pusher_3/3
Pushed: Pusher_4/4
Pushed: Pusher_5/5
Pushed: Pusher_6/6
Pushed: Pusher_7/7
Pushed: Pusher_8/8
Pushed: Pusher_9/9
Pushed: Pusher_10/10
Pushed: Pusher_11/11
Pushed: Pusher_12/12
Pushed: Pusher_13/13
Pushed: Pusher_14/14
Pushed: Pusher_15/15
Pushed: Pusher_16/16
Pushed: Pusher_17/17
Pushed: Pusher_18/18
Pushed: Pusher_19/19
Pushed: Pusher_20/20
Pushed: Pusher_21/21
Pushed: Pusher_22/22
Pushed: Pusher_23/23
Pushed: Pusher_24/24
Pushed: Pusher_25/25
Pushed: Pusher_26/26
Popped: Pusher_1 / 25
Retrieved: Pusher_1
Popped: Pusher_2 / 24
Retrieved: Pusher_2
Popped: Pusher_3 / 23
Retrieved: Pusher_3
Popped: Pusher_4 / 22
Retrieved: Pusher_4
Popped: Pusher_5 / 21
Retrieved: Pusher_5
Popped: Pusher_6 / 20
Retrieved: Pusher_6
Popped: Pusher_7 / 19
Retrieved: Pusher_7
Popped: Pusher_8 / 18
Retrieved: Pusher_8
Pushed: Pusher_27/19
Pushed: Pusher_28/20
Pushed: Pusher_29/21
Pushed: Pusher_30/22
Pushed: Pusher_31/23
Pushed: Pusher_32/24
Pushed: Pusher_33/25
Pushed: Pusher_34/26
Pushed: Pusher_35/27
Pushed: Pusher_36/28
Pushed: Pusher_37/29
Pushed: Pusher_38/30
Pushed: Pusher_39/31
Pushed: Pusher_40/32
Pushed: Pusher_41/33
Pushed: Pusher_42/34
Pushed: Pusher_43/35
Pushed: Pusher_44/36
Pushed: Pusher_45/37
Pushed: Pusher_46/38
Pushed: Pusher_47/39
Pushed: Pusher_48/40
Pushed: Pusher_49/41
Pushed: Pusher_50/42
Pushed: Pusher_51/43
Pushed: Pusher_52/44
Pushed: Pusher_53/45
Pushed: Pusher_54/46
Pushed: Pusher_55/47
Pushed: Pusher_56/48
Pushed: Pusher_57/49
Pushed: Pusher_58/50
Pushed: Pusher_59/51
Pushed: Pusher_60/52
Pushed: Pusher_61/53
Pushed: Pusher_62/54
Pushed: Pusher_63/55
Pushed: Pusher_64/56
Pushed: Pusher_65/57
Pushed: Pusher_66/58
Pushed: Pusher_67/59
Pushed: Pusher_68/60
Pushed: Pusher_69/61
Pushed: Pusher_70/62
Pushed: Pusher_71/63
Pushed: Pusher_72/64
Pushed: Pusher_73/65
Pushed: Pusher_74/66
Pushed: Pusher_75/67
Pushed: Pusher_76/68
Pushed: Pusher_77/69
Pushed: Pusher_78/70
Pushed: Pusher_79/71
Pushed: Pusher_80/72
Pushed: Pusher_81/73
Pushed: Pusher_82/74
Pushed: Pusher_83/75
Pushed: Pusher_84/76
Pushed: Pusher_85/77
Pushed: Pusher_86/78
Pushed: Pusher_87/79
Pushed: Pusher_88/80
Pushed: Pusher_89/81
Pushed: Pusher_90/82
Pushed: Pusher_91/83
Pushed: Pusher_92/84
Pushed: Pusher_93/85
Pushed: Pusher_94/86
Pushed: Pusher_95/87
Pushed: Pusher_96/88
Pushed: Pusher_97/89
Pushed: Pusher_98/90
Pushed: Pusher_99/91
Pushed: Pusher_100/92
Popped: Pusher_9 / 91
Retrieved: Pusher_9
Popped: Pusher_10 / 90
Retrieved: Pusher_10
Popped: Pusher_11 / 89
Retrieved: Pusher_11
Popped: Pusher_12 / 88
Retrieved: Pusher_12
Popped: Pusher_13 / 87
Retrieved: Pusher_13
Popped: Pusher_14 / 86
Retrieved: Pusher_14
Popped: Pusher_15 / 85
Retrieved: Pusher_15
Popped: Pusher_16 / 84
Retrieved: Pusher_16
Popped: Pusher_17 / 83
Retrieved: Pusher_17
Popped: Pusher_18 / 82
Retrieved: Pusher_18
Popped: Pusher_19 / 81
Retrieved: Pusher_19
Popped: Pusher_20 / 80
Retrieved: Pusher_20
Popped: Pusher_21 / 79
Retrieved: Pusher_21
Popped: Pusher_22 / 78
Retrieved: Pusher_22
Popped: Pusher_23 / 77
Retrieved: Pusher_23
Popped: Pusher_24 / 76
Retrieved: Pusher_24
Popped: Pusher_25 / 75
Retrieved: Pusher_25
Popped: Pusher_26 / 74
Retrieved: Pusher_26
Popped: Pusher_27 / 73
Retrieved: Pusher_27
Popped: Pusher_28 / 72
Retrieved: Pusher_28
Popped: Pusher_29 / 71
Retrieved: Pusher_29
Popped: Pusher_30 / 70
Retrieved: Pusher_30
Popped: Pusher_31 / 69
Retrieved: Pusher_31
Popped: Pusher_32 / 68
Retrieved: Pusher_32
Popped: Pusher_33 / 67
Retrieved: Pusher_33
Popped: Pusher_34 / 66
Retrieved: Pusher_34
Popped: Pusher_35 / 65
Retrieved: Pusher_35
Popped: Pusher_36 / 64
Retrieved: Pusher_36
Popped: Pusher_37 / 63
Retrieved: Pusher_37
Popped: Pusher_38 / 62
Retrieved: Pusher_38
Popped: Pusher_39 / 61
Retrieved: Pusher_39
Popped: Pusher_40 / 60
Retrieved: Pusher_40
Popped: Pusher_41 / 59
Retrieved: Pusher_41
Popped: Pusher_42 / 58
Retrieved: Pusher_42
Popped: Pusher_43 / 57
Retrieved: Pusher_43
Popped: Pusher_44 / 56
Retrieved: Pusher_44
Popped: Pusher_45 / 55
Retrieved: Pusher_45
Popped: Pusher_46 / 54
Retrieved: Pusher_46
Popped: Pusher_47 / 53
Retrieved: Pusher_47
Popped: Pusher_48 / 52
Retrieved: Pusher_48
Popped: Pusher_49 / 51
Retrieved: Pusher_49
Popped: Pusher_50 / 50
Retrieved: Pusher_50
Popped: Pusher_51 / 49
Retrieved: Pusher_51
Popped: Pusher_52 / 48
Retrieved: Pusher_52
Popped: Pusher_53 / 47
Retrieved: Pusher_53
Popped: Pusher_54 / 46
Retrieved: Pusher_54
Popped: Pusher_55 / 45
Retrieved: Pusher_55
Popped: Pusher_56 / 44
Retrieved: Pusher_56
Popped: Pusher_57 / 43
Retrieved: Pusher_57
Popped: Pusher_58 / 42
Retrieved: Pusher_58
Popped: Pusher_59 / 41
Retrieved: Pusher_59
Popped: Pusher_60 / 40
Retrieved: Pusher_60
Popped: Pusher_61 / 39
Retrieved: Pusher_61
Popped: Pusher_62 / 38
Retrieved: Pusher_62
Popped: Pusher_63 / 37
Retrieved: Pusher_63
Popped: Pusher_64 / 36
Retrieved: Pusher_64
Popped: Pusher_65 / 35
Retrieved: Pusher_65
Popped: Pusher_66 / 34
Retrieved: Pusher_66
Popped: Pusher_67 / 33
Retrieved: Pusher_67
Popped: Pusher_68 / 32
Retrieved: Pusher_68
Popped: Pusher_69 / 31
Retrieved: Pusher_69
Popped: Pusher_70 / 30
Retrieved: Pusher_70
Popped: Pusher_71 / 29
Retrieved: Pusher_71
Popped: Pusher_72 / 28
Retrieved: Pusher_72
Popped: Pusher_73 / 27
Retrieved: Pusher_73
Popped: Pusher_74 / 26
Retrieved: Pusher_74
Popped: Pusher_75 / 25
Retrieved: Pusher_75
Popped: Pusher_76 / 24
Retrieved: Pusher_76
Popped: Pusher_77 / 23
Retrieved: Pusher_77
Popped: Pusher_78 / 22
Retrieved: Pusher_78
Popped: Pusher_79 / 21
Retrieved: Pusher_79
Popped: Pusher_80 / 20
Retrieved: Pusher_80
Popped: Pusher_81 / 19
Retrieved: Pusher_81
Popped: Pusher_82 / 18
Retrieved: Pusher_82
Popped: Pusher_83 / 17
Retrieved: Pusher_83
Popped: Pusher_84 / 16
Retrieved: Pusher_84
Popped: Pusher_85 / 15
Retrieved: Pusher_85
Popped: Pusher_86 / 14
Retrieved: Pusher_86
Popped: Pusher_87 / 13
Retrieved: Pusher_87
Popped: Pusher_88 / 12
Retrieved: Pusher_88
Popped: Pusher_89 / 11
Retrieved: Pusher_89
Popped: Pusher_90 / 10
Retrieved: Pusher_90
Popped: Pusher_91 / 9
Retrieved: Pusher_91
Popped: Pusher_92 / 8
Retrieved: Pusher_92
Popped: Pusher_93 / 7
Retrieved: Pusher_93
Popped: Pusher_94 / 6
Retrieved: Pusher_94
Popped: Pusher_95 / 5
Retrieved: Pusher_95
Popped: Pusher_96 / 4
Retrieved: Pusher_96
Popped: Pusher_97 / 3
Retrieved: Pusher_97
Popped: Pusher_98 / 2
Retrieved: Pusher_98
Popped: Pusher_99 / 1
Retrieved: Pusher_99
Popped: Pusher_100 / 0
Retrieved: Pusher_100
```